# Tomcat Rewrite Valve - How to Keep Pretty URL on Client Browser

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

I'm using Tomcat **Rewrite Valve API** so that I could publish my webapp URLs as '*pretty URL*'. My issue is that after successful URL rewriting, the browser url address did not keep the pretty URL, but display to the final ugly URL that I tried to hide in the first place, therefore defeating the purpose of using this nice API. I understand with Apache **mod_rewrite module**, the browser would keep the pretty URL that user enters after the successful rewrite; hence hiding nitty-gritty URI and params from naked eyes. Is it possible to achieve this with Rewrite Valve API? How?

Configs

1. Server = Tomcat Apache 9.0.30
2. [webapp]/META-INF/**context.xml**

`<Context override="true" >
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Context>`

3. [webapp]/WEB-INF/**rewrite.config**

   `RewriteRule ^/support/contactUs/?$ ?page=page_supportID&fragment=fragment_contactUsID [NC,L]`

**Use-Case**: User enters on their browser pretty URL: `http://example.com/support/contactUs`

**Expected**: The rewrite rule applies and opens the actual (ugly) URL = `http://example.com?page=page_supportID&fragment=fragment_contactUsID`, and user browser still displays pretty URL = `http://example.com/support/contactUs`.

**Actual**: The rewrite rule applied and opened the actual (ugly) URL = `http://example.com?page=page_supportID&fragment=fragment_contactUsID`. HOWEVER the browser url address also displayed that ugly url to user, instead of keeping the pretty one.

Answer (score 0):

**NOT possible**!

I wish I was wrong, however! After studying more of this behavior, for the URL Rewrite scheme-of-thing, we may not be able to control how client browser would handle and display after-redirecting URL on its url bar using this API.

Tomcat RewriteValve API has done what it is supposed to do = By **DEFAULT** returning proper `HTTP status code 302` back to the client while redirecting the URL. Per [Tomcat doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html#redirect):

> If no code is given, an HTTP response of 302 (FOUND, previously MOVED
>   TEMPORARILY) will be returned.

We can confrm by reading network HTTP request/response stacktrace. For the purpose of this question, HTTP response 302 is what we expected to see. Per [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302):

> HTTP 302 Found ... A browser redirects to this page but search engines
>   don't update their links to the resource ... Even if the spec requires
>   the method (and the body) not to be altered when the redirection is
>   performed, not all user-agents conform here - you can still find this
>   type of bugged software out there.

O welp!